# DataFormComboBoxField bind

Tags: silverlight, combobox, dataform

Can someone give me a simple example how can I bind DataFormComboBoxField ItemsSource to DataFormComboBoxField SelectedItem. I search over the net but didn't found a similar example

Answer (score 0):

Preassumption: Telerik rad controls for silverlight/wpf.

If your data in your first DataFormComboBoxField holds combobox data items then then the simplest idea would be something like this:

```
<telerik:DataFormComboBoxField ItemSource="{Binding ...}" x:Name="FirstComboBox" />
<telerik:DataFormComboBoxField ItemSource="{Binding SelectedItem.SomeDataList, ElementName=FirstComboBox}" />
```

If your second list needs to be derived data from your first list, then you will have to re-write your first combobox to a DataFormDataField and include a RadComboBox control and hook on to the SelectionChanged event to get the key to enable the derived data.

hope this helps.